# Big discrepancy between firefox and chrome rendering

Tags: html, css

The same html/css is returning very different results... What's going on here?

I have included all of the relevant CSS and the entire HTML markup for the page so you can see the structure. You can find the html for the search bar down near the bottom of the included code where "search1.png" is.

I've already been having a problem with the drop-down menus rendering at slightly different sizes/positions between the two browsers and I suspect it is because they render the text in side the main navigation items in slightly different ways.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!!

FIREFOX:
[image: 1]

CHROME:
[image: 1]

```
nav ul{
text-align:right;
font-size:0;
list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li{
display:inline-block;
height:54px;
padding:0 20 0 20;
background:white;
color:black;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 54px;
font-size:15;   
}

nav ul li:hover{
background:#222;
color:white;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul ul {
position: absolute; 
padding-top:15px;
padding-bottom:15px;
padding-left:0px;
background:#222;
z-index:100;
border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
overflow:hidden;
}

/*    SEARCH   */
li.red:nth-child(7) > ul:nth-child(1){
width: 328px;
margin-left: -277px;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 54px;
vertical-align: middle;
padding-top:15px;
padding-bottom:15px;
position:relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>SENECA AV</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="top" class="bars"><img src="senecalogo1.png" alt="SENECA">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>  PRODUCTS
        <ul>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>  CATALOG
        <ul class="left">
          <li>STUFF</li>
          <li>THINGS</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>  SHOP
      </li>
      <li class="red">  COMPANY
      </li>
      <li class="red">  HELP
        <ul>
          <li>  Ask a question  </li>
          <li>  Register your product  </li>
          <li>  Returns/Exchanges  </li>
          <li>  Warranty  </li>
          <li>  FAQ  </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="red">  TRADE
        <ul>
          <li>  Open an account  </li>
          <li>  Online Retailers  </li>
          <li>  Retail Stores  </li>
          <li>  Contract  </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="red" style="padding:0 8 0 8;background-image:url('search1.png');width:43px;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;">       
         <ul>
          <input type="text" value="item, number, SKU"> 
          <input type="submit" value="search"> 
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="red" style="padding:0 15 0 0;">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div id="bottom" class="bars"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please create jsfiddle where we can see your problem

Answer (score 1):

After a bunch of fooling around I found the issue. It was slightly complicated which is probably why I couldn't see a solution sooner.

I was missing a DOCTYPE declaration at the top of the page.

Adding this instantly broke the page and made the entire navigation disappear because I wasn't properly declaring CSS size values. A quick look at the console explained which properties were at issue allowing me to fix them all one by one.

for example:

```
padding:0 20 0 20;
```

needs to be

```
padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;
```

Once all relevant properties had 'px' appended to their values the menu items reappeared.

Also,

```
nav ul ul {
line-height:15px;
}
```

needed to be added to get rid of the riduculous over-padding apparent in the Chrome example above which also appeared in Firefox once the DOCTYPE was added because...

```
line-height:54px;
```

was being inherited from the parent li (nav ul li)